# Strange error in flow v 0.52 that did not appear in v 0.50

Tags: flowtype

When checking the following code:

```
// @flow

'use strict';

/*::
type UiTableConfigColumnFilterType = string | Array<number> | {from: number | Date, to: number | Date};
*/

function validateColumnFilter(columnFilter/*: UiTableConfigColumnFilterType*/) {
    columnFilter.from = 1;
    columnFilter.to = 2;
}

const filter/*: UiTableConfigColumnFilterType*/ = {
    from: 0,
    to: 0
};

validateColumnFilter(filter);
```

This is the output

```
Error: index.js:10
 10:    columnFilter.from = 1;
                     ^^^^ property `from`. Property cannot be assigned on
 10:    columnFilter.from = 1;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^ string

Error: index.js:10
 10:    columnFilter.from = 1;
                     ^^^^ property `from`. Property not found in
 10:    columnFilter.from = 1;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^ Array

Error: index.js:11
 11:    columnFilter.to = 2;
                     ^^ property `to`. Property cannot be assigned on
 11:    columnFilter.to = 2;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^ string

Error: index.js:11
 11:    columnFilter.to = 2;
                     ^^ property `to`. Property not found in
 11:    columnFilter.to = 2;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^ Array
```

and I do not understand why flow would not pick up the `{from: number | Date,   to: number | Date}` part of the definition of UiTableConfigColumnFilterType ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must refine [disjoint unions](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/#toc-disjoint-unions) before you interact with them. Flow is not saying that this particular usage of `validateColumnFilter` is unsafe, but that `validateColumnFilter`, as written, is not safe for all possible argument types. For example, if you passed an `Array` (which is a valid `UiTableConfigColumnFilterType`), you would be assigning the `to` and `from` properties to an Array, which is something that flow specifically guards against.

As written, you could perform the refinement like so:

```
function validateColumnFilter(columnFilter/*: UiTableConfigColumnFilterType*/) {
  if (typeof columnFilter !== 'string' && !(columnFilter instanceof Array)) {
    columnFilter.from = 1;
    columnFilter.to = 2;
  }
}
```

Or, if you plan on handling the other cases, here's a possible way to refine each case (with contrived examples):

```
function validateColumnFilter(columnFilter/*: UiTableConfigColumnFilterType*/) {
  if (typeof columnFilter === 'string') {
      // Handle the string-based column filter
      return columnFilter + ' valid!';
  } else if (columnFilter instanceof Array) {
      // Handle the Array-based column filter 
      columnFilter.push(5);
  } else {
    // Handle the object-based column filter
    columnFilter.from = 1;
    columnFilter.to = 2;
  }
}
```